# after_cancel doesn't work in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, timer, countdown

I made a simple countdown in my trivia game and every time that I go to the next slide it doesn't cancel the previous countdown timer and overlaps with the previous one.
I searched about that on the web and found the after_cancel function that cancels the timer after I go to the next slide and then I recreate it. But it still overlaps even after I added this function.
I think that I didn't give the after_cancel the correct arguments.

```
       from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

WaitState = StringVar()
count = 10
button_label = StringVar()

def clear():
   WaitState.set(1)
   for widgets in window.winfo_children():
      widgets.destroy()

def clear_time():
   clear()


   time_up_label = Label(
      window,
      text="Time is up",
      bg = "#6378ff",
      fg="#000000",
      font=("Arial", 100,"bold"))
   time_up_label.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.5,anchor = 'center')

   continue_but = Button(
      window,
      text="Continue",
      font=("Knewave",25,"bold"),
      bg="#942222",
      width=11,
      height=5,
      command=clear)
   continue_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)
                

   continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)

def button_countdown(i, label):
   if i > 0:
      i -= 1
      label.set(i)
      window.after_id = window.after(1000, lambda: button_countdown(i, label))
   else:
      window.after_cancel(window.after_id)
      clear_time()

for index in range(5):
   continue_but = Button(
      window,
      text="Continue",
      font=("Knewave",25,"bold"),
      bg="#942222",
      width=11,
      height=5,
      command=clear)
   continue_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)
      
   button_label.set(count)
   timer_label = Label(
      window,
      textvariable=button_label,
      bg="#6378ff",
      fg="#ff0000",
      font=("Arial",46,"bold"))
   timer_label.pack()

   button_countdown(count, button_label)
   
   continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example? How do you call `button_countdown`? When do you call it? Right now there is no point to the `.after_cancel(...)` and I think you should have put it in a different place. There is no way for us to give you an answer unless we have a minimal working example of your problem.

Comment: @TheLizzard my code is 500 lines if you want I can provide you that and tell you where it is

Comment: Isn't there a way for you to create a simple window with a button that activates the function and shows your problem. The problem is that if I am looking at 500 lines of code, I am likely to miss things out.

Comment: Make an example such that this issue will be reproduced there, in this way, there is a good chance that you will figure out what is wrong yourself.

Comment: @TheLizzard I added here a simple example. Wait a couple of seconds and hit the continue button to see what happens and how it overlaps.

Comment: Somehow it is still 75 lines long, however, can you explain your objective here?

Comment: @CoolCloud I need to know how to store the after_id.

Comment: @ItamarGayor The way you store the `after_id` is fine. To solve your problem move the `window.after_cancel(window.after_id)` inside your `clear` function.